# URL issue in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, opencart, session-cookies

Our website in OpenCart is working fine. But after changing  server we see some code in URL example:

Old URL:
http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62_66

After shifting server its showing:
http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62_66#.VZBEyFIwDzM

And its code "#.VZBEyFIwDzM" loaded in URL after loading page.

Comment: Can you include the .htaccess file?

Comment: yes we included the .htaccess file

Comment: @CmsCoders he ment post your .htaccess file here ..

Comment: SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (googlebot|bingbot|yahoo!\sslurp) is_search_bot
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
allow from 1.6.0.0/15
allow from 1.22.0.0/15
allow from 1.38.0.0/15
allow from 1.186.0.0/15
allow from 5.56.18.0/24
allow from 5.56.20.0/24
allow from 5.56.21.128/25
allow from 5.56.23.0/25
deny from all
Allow from env=is_search_bot
</Limit>

Comment: but after the removing .htaccess file  its  showing same code in url

Comment: Be careful because xxxxxxxx.com is actually a real website.  (If someone try to click on it)

Comment: Sorry i just put as example you can check watchokart.com you will get the idea